# Getting datas from a generated form (php/ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm generating a form with php/mysql. I'm using checkbox that looks like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_3" name="my2_3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_4" name="my2_4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_5" name="my2_5" />
```

My issue is to retrieve those data (whether the checkbox is checked or not and the id).
How can I retrieve that with php without knowing in advance what will be the $_POST[""] to request?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_3" name="my[]" value="my2_3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_4" name="my[]" value="my2_4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="my2_5" name="my[]" value="my2_5" />
```

I changed the name attribute to an array,

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
   $check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { ... }` to iterate over all POST vars.

Comment: Thanx a lot! If i understood it right I would have some thing like that for <input type="checkbox" id="my2_3" name="my2_3" /> $key = my2_3 and $value = false

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier for you if you changed the `name` attribute to create a php array. Check the documentation on [creating arrays in HTML form](http://php.net/manual/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are only posted when they are ticked. So you need to inspect `$_POST` and use `isset()` to determine whether or not the key you are looking for (the name attribute of a checkbox) is present. If it is, the checkbox was ticked. If not, the checkbox was unticked.